# В MongoDB можно задать size коллекции, а потом его можно увеличить у этой коллекции?

Tags: mongodb

В MongoDB можно задать size коллекции, а потом его можно увеличить у этой коллекции?
Если да то какой командой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да можно.

- Чтобы задать size  коллекции можно использовать [`db.createCollection()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createCollection/#db.createCollection)
- чтобы изменить можно использовать команд [`convertToCapped`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/convertToCapped/)

Comment: Это делается легко и не имеет подводных камней?)

Comment: конечно ледко и не имеет подводных камней для большее инфо нужно читать документация.